# Javascript looping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is something easy that is just eluding me.

Anyway, I have a simple function that loops through a series of six images and text and hides and shows them based on which one is visible.

Issue I'm having is that when it gets to the last image, it should just start over with the first but instead it goes back to the middle image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval('testAnimation()', 5 * 1000);
show = 0;
function testAnimation() {
    $("#headerImage" + show).fadeOut();
    $("#headerText" + show).fadeOut();
    if (show == 5) {
        show = 0;
    }
    else {
        show++;
    }
    $("#headerImage" + show).fadeIn();
    $("#headerText" + show).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

So it should go like this:

```
Hide: 0 Show: 1
Hide: 1 Show: 2
Hide: 2 Show: 3
Hide: 3 Show: 4
Hide: 4 Show: 5
Hide: 5 Show: 0
```

But what happens after 4, 5 is 3, 4.  Then it goes to 5, 0.

Any ideas as to why?

You can see the behavior here:
http://www.findyourgeek.com/index-copy.php

Comment: change the setInterval call to as follows: setInterval(testAnimation, 5000);

Comment: Does it always go 5, 3, 4 or do you occasionally get random order processing?  Is it possible that your animation / fading is taking longer than an interval, which would "back up" the functions and eventually cause things to end up out of order?

Comment: Is it skipping 3/4 before going to 4/5? Did you rearrange the elements on the page and forget to renumber them?

Comment: You can see the behavior here:  http://www.findyourgeek.com/index-copy.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary:** Issue was a global variable name conflict for the global variable named `show` between two different functions (that had nothing to do with one another) in the same page.

Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pahZx/.  There must be an issue with your HTML or other code.  Please show your HTML and rest of the page if you want further help.

I see you've now included a link to your actual implementation.

**Edit:**

OK, I can now see the issue in your actual site.  I can even see it happening in the Chrome debugger. It seems to only happen the first iteration through.  I don't know for sure what the issue could be, but my first guess is a global variable conflict with the variable `show`.  I would suggest these changes:

1. Change the name of your `show` global variable to something a lot more unique.  Perhaps there is a conflict somewhere with something else using that global name (I can come up with no other explanation for why the value would be changed from 5 to 3 between invocations of the function.
2. Add `var` in front of the declaration of that variable.
3. Get rid of the text in the `setInterval` call and refer to the function directly

This is what your code would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(testAnimation, 5 * 1000);
var mySlideshowCntr = 0;
function testAnimation()
{
    $("#headerImage" + mySlideshowCntr).fadeOut();
    $("#headerText" + mySlideshowCntr).fadeOut();
    if (mySlideshowCntr == 5) 
        { mySlideshowCntr = 0; } 
    else 
        { mySlideshowCntr++; }
    $("#headerImage" + mySlideshowCntr).fadeIn();
    $("#headerText" + mySlideshowCntr).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

I do see some code in your page that I think is setting a global named `show`:

```
// ( main ) index.php
otherSpotlightTimer = 0
function refreshOtherSpotlight()
{   
    if (!$("#login").is(":visible"))
    {
        if (otherSpotlightTimer<=3)
        {
            otherSpotlightTimer++;
            $("#otherSpotlight"+otherSpotlightTimer).hide();
            switch (otherSpotlightTimer)
            {
                case 1:show=2;break;
                case 2:show=3;break;
                case 3:show=1;break;
            }
            $("#otherSpotlight"+show).fadeIn();
        }
        if (otherSpotlightTimer > 3)
        {
            $('.qtip').each(function(){$(this).qtip("api").destroy()});
            $.post("/scripts/refreshotherspotlight.php", 
                { fromsubmit : "true" },
                function(data)
                {
                    if (data != "")
                    {
                        $("#otherSpotlight1").hide();
                        $("#otherSpotlight1").html(data);
                        $("#otherSpotlight1").fadeIn("slow");
                        //height = $("#otherSpotlight").height();
                        //$("#otherSpotlight").css('min-height', height+'px');
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        attachqTips();
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**

I can verify with a breakpoint that this other code is, indeed, setting the global variable `show` and that is causing a problem.  If you change your global variable name to something unique, it should solve the problem.  This is a classic lesson in global namespacing.

Comment: findyourgeek.com/index-copy.php

Comment: If you look at it when it gets to the last item, you can see it show another item (look at the text) before going back and properly cycling.  I see this in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Tom, OK I see it now in your actual page (only on the first iteration).  I have added some suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, only on the first iteration.  Changed the code to what you have and still getting the same behavior.  Very odd.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: There was one typo in the code I gave you (I didn't change one occurrence of `show`.  I'd suggest updating your code once more.  I also did find some code that looks like it is setting a global named `show`.  Also, the publicly accessible copy of your page doesn't look like the code was changed at all.

Comment: Changed the code and it's still happening.  Damned if I know why, should be good to go at this point I would think.

Comment: @Tom - I can verify with a breakpoint that this other code is, indeed, setting the global variable `show` and that is causing a problem.  If you change your global variable name to something unique, it should solve the problem.  This is a classic lesson in global namespacing or avoidance of global variables.

Comment: I changed it from `show` to `mySlideshowCntr` as per your code above, still happening though =(

Comment: The var name isn't changed in the publicly accessible page that I can see.  I can verify in the debugger that this is what's causing the problem.

Comment: Ugh, sorry.  I was working on the development page instead of the production one, my bad as they say.  I've updated the live page with your implementation and it indeed works now.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Cool.  Those are hard to find.  Great lesson on the dangers of generic names for global variables without any namespacing protection.

Comment: Yup, glad to have gotten that part squared away, now onto the next problem =)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're experiencing. This works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wMK6H/3/

Except in my example everything is shown to begin with so you will have to let it do an initial run-through all the numbers first before you see the full effect.

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out what's up either.  I moved the development page into live so you can see the behavior: http://www.findyourgeek.com/index-copy.php

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the code. here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wMK6H/2/

just to summarize

```
 <div id="headerImage1" class="image">1</div>
<div id="headerImage2" class="image" style="display:none">2</div>
<div id="headerImage3" class="image" style="display:none">3</div>
<div id="headerImage4" class="image" style="display:none">4</div>
<div id="headerImage5" class="image" style="display:none">5</div>
<div id="headerImage6" class="image"  style="display:none">6</div>
```

the js code:

```
setInterval(testAnimation, 5000);
show = 1;
function testAnimation()
{
$(".image").fadeOut();
if (show == 5) 
    { show = 0; } 
else 
    { show++; }
$("#headerImage" + show).fadeIn();
$("#headerText" + show).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: You fade out every image on every iteration?  Why?  That is not necessary.

Comment: Plus your code expects images to be numbered 0 to 5, not 1 to 6.

Comment: I reused some existing code.. I was not goin to spend too much time on it.. whatever was there i reused..

Comment: This solution is not correct because you're using images starting with 1 and ending in 6. (6 elements) The iterator is from 0 to 4 (5 elements) since at 5 it goes back to 0.

Comment: @jfriend00, are you suggesting that the browser is going to be brought to its knees by hiding 6 images?

Comment: like I said I reused your code DeviantSeev I dint wanna rewrite code.. the author should get an idea and go ahead.. its nt abt giving him the perfect code..

Comment: @user350374 - hiding six images when only one needs to be hidden is just inefficient.  I consider is wasteful coding.  Don't know if it makes a difference here, but I don't consider it good practice.  You are free to have a different opinion.  Anyway, the issue had nothing to do with this (it was a global variable name conflict).  Why don't you give yourself a recognizable name on SO?

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/SYhhH/2/) to one previously posted but completely independent.  The point being that the code you've provided seems to work fine. I checked out your link too....

I noticed two issues.  After the last headerImage/headerText (the 6th one) the animation seems to take twice as long but does eventually rotate to the correct image.  So its working but seems to take a break at the end of the sequence.

There is a ghosting of the text in the headline.  Instead of using fadeOut, use hide.  You have 4 animations in your function.  Default time for each is 400ms so you'd think that 1600ms would finish before your next interval elapses however, maybe not?

**Perhaps there is an issue with the queue where something isn't finishing correctly?  Maybe things are getting screwed up in the jquery animation queue because one thing is finishing before another starts so the show++ hasn't executed.**

Comment: It's not ghosting, it's the animation showing item 5 (count = 4) and not hiding item 6 (count = 5).  Even stranger is that it only does this the first time through, after that  it scrolls fine.